# 64 bit alternative to SunPkcs11 implementation

Tags: java, encryption

We use a middle-ware to build software applications which is installed over JDK 1.6.30 64 bit setup.

We recently got a requirement to sign certain requests using USB token. I googled around and found out that an implementation is provided by Sun in the name of SunPKCS11. But, the same is only available in 32 bit JRE until Java 8.

I want to know if there are any alternative non commercial implementations available out there which I can make use of.

Please note that upgrading Java or changing the architecture is not an option as there is a high dependency on the middleware.